# ActiveRecord relationships and the object model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Hi I recently ran into this when trying to do the following:

```
posts = User.first.posts
posts.find {|p| "p.id" == 123} => ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Post without an ID
```

That is trying to call an ActiveRecord find. It's expecting:

```
posts.find(123)
```

But I dont want to query the db again. So I need to do:

```
posts.to_a.find {|p| "p.id" == 123}
```

I though I was dealing with an Array, according to posts.class. Why to I have to call to_a on it?

```
posts.class => Array
posts.superclass => ActiveRecord::Base
```

Why can I call superclass on posts if it's (presumably) an instance of Array and why does it return ActiveRecord::Base?

Also:

```
posts.ancestors.include? ActiveRecord::Base => false
```

Why is that false if ActiveRecord::Base is the superclass of the posts array?

One more. If I do:

```
posts.instance_methods(false)
```

It returns the instance methods of the class of the relationship, i.e. Post. That seems weird since posts is an Array. Similarly if I create a "regular" array:

```
a = [1, 2]
a.instance_methods(false) => NoMethodError: undefined method `instance_methods' for [1, 2]:Array
```

So the array returned via an ActiveRecord relationship query is sort of like an array but not...it seems like it inherits from ActiveRecord, but it doesn't...or something. Just when I thought I was getting a solid grasp of the Ruby object model :) Maybe an under-the-hood look at ActiveRecord would help. I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking I guess.

This is just a curiosity thing. Any help/guidance is appreciated

Comment: Why are you comparing a string with an int in the block? Why are you doing `posts.find {|p| "p.id" == 123}` instead of `p.id` ?

Comment: yeah that was a typo. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
posts.detect {|p| p.id == 123}
```

`find` is an alias of `detect`, but it is shadowed by the `find` method on the ActiveRecord collection proxy you get back from `posts`.

Answer (score 0):

The find method is only available on the ActiveRecord::Base class.It's a class method, not an instance method.

Yes, that's not exactly an array, but it does behave like an Enumerable.

In this case you could use select

```
posts.select{|p| p.id == 123}.first
```

I added the .first at the end, because select will return another array, be it with just one element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct method would be to use `detect` rather than `select` here, as `detect` will return the first element it comes across and stop looking. Just a helpful FYI.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ActiveRecord::Base` overrides the `#find` method that you want from [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001484). This is why you need to convert it to an array which doesn't have the overwritten find method.

Answer (score 0):

```
posts.ancestors.include? ActiveRecord::Base => false
```

Is false because posts is a collection of Post objects, not a descendant of `ActiveRecord::Base`.  Any individual item inside of the posts collection will be a descendant of `ActiveRecord::Base`